# Google custom search API only provide limited results

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I am using Google custom search API

normally we frame the keyword with quote before calling the api.

for eg: "Jerry Wimbrow"

In google if I use the above keyword with quote, we are receiving 300 URLs in the result.

But we don't know why the same result is not coming while using the below API request.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="my google API key"&cx=000795651442911119357:t1ad9f3mgzi&q=%22Jerry%20Wimbrow%22
```

URL's.

Can you please explain why we are getting only 1 result for the Jerry wimbrow keyword whereas other keyword receive with more URL?

Comment: please read about parameter use in google custom search, q=( is standing for query) mean when you have some query then you get multiple result else you 1 simple resulte

Comment: were u able to figure out?

Answer (score 0):

Its just a Google API's limitation.

As an hacky workaround try to use the - character with your search query.
For instance, you know that the majority of the search results contain the keyword "apple", then append the token: -apple to your search query, so the search is going to return you the results that doesn't contain the word apple.

Example

First query:

```
Jerry Wimbrow
```

Second query:

```
Jerry Wimbrow -whitepages
```

Third query:

```
Jerry Wimbrow -whitepages -mylife
```

Then you collect all the results (is a set's union) from your queries.

**Pros:**

Works;

**Cons**:

It costs.